# how to know which docker container, image was ON before server got shut down

Tags: docker

I have a server in which the docker containers were running. Server got shutdown. How to know which container was on; Because container list are empty now.

[image: docker images]

[image: docker contaienrs list empty]

Comment: If you re-run `docker-compose up -d`, it will recreate the things that need to be up; you don't need to reverse-engineer that.  (This also isn't the sort of programming question that's on-topic for Stack Overflow, you might ask [DevOps.SE](https://devops.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).  It's also much better form to include the text of the commands you run and their output rather than hard-to-read screenshots of terminals.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this command to see whats container is running :

`docker ps`

To see all containers whaterver it doesnot running or is up:

`docker ps -a`

**And check time container went down.**

Bring it up :

`docker start container_id`

Comment: thank you for respond, i tryed those commands but containers list are empty.

Comment: try to use root user to run that command.

Answer (score -1):

Found out that there where no containers started. If it where, the containers would of been stopped.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).